Kotlin use file chosen by user from gallery as a resource, that will stay after closing app
I'm using this
val pickimg = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                startActivityForResult(pickimg,100)

and this
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        val facjasejf = getSharedPreferences("facjasejf", 0)
        val facjaeditor = facjasejf.edit()
        val facjata = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.facjata)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == 100) {
            val imageUri = data?.data
            facjata.setImageURI(imageUri)
            facjaeditor.putString("uri",imageUri.toString())
            facjaeditor.commit()
        }
}

to give user option to choose image from gallery and set it as source of imageView
Then I tried to do this:
val facjasejf = getSharedPreferences("facjasejf", 0)
val obraz = facjasejf.getString("uri",null)
if (obraz != null){
    facjata.setImageURI(obraz.toUri())
}

to load it (when user have alredy chosen it) on new MainActivity opening, however my app crashes. I specifically want file in my drawable folder so user can't edit it or really acess it
I alredy have implemented READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. I would like my app to somehow copy selected image from gallery to drawable folder and use it as ImageView source pernamently. If it is not possible in drawable folder any different folder or methon where user cannot edit the file is good.


I would like my app to somehow copy selected image from gallery to drawable folder

That is not an option. Drawables are not files on the filesystem of the device — they are only entries in an APK file.

If it is not possible in drawable folder any different folder or methon where user cannot edit the file is good.

Use ContentResolver and openInputStream() to get an InputStream on the content identified by the Uri that you get back from your ACTION_PICK request. Call getFilesDir() on Context to get a directory that can be used by your app, that the user does not have direct access to. Copy the bytes from the InputStream to a FileOutputStream on some file in that directory.
